# How to rig a stack so that moving one object moves all the others in relation to one another?

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes

I'm trying to automate a stack of planes bouncing on Z, from 0" for all planes, to a factor of + 1" for each plane, relative to the plane below it.

I have made each 'above' plane a child of the plane below it, which works, but it still means I have to keyframe every plane.

Is there a way to rig this so that I have one 'control object' that when moved up on Z, will move every plane, but in relation to one before it?

In other words...

All planes at "Base" 0:
[image: Base Layer]

All planes moved up on Z relative to each other:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Remove the parent-child relationship, create an empty (control object), hover over its Z loc value and right click "Copy as new driver".

Hover over the Z loc value of the first plane and right click "Paste driver".

Hover over the Z loc value of the 2nd plane and right click "Paste driver", right click "Edit driver" switch from "Average value" to "Scripted expression" and set the expression "location*2".

Copy this driver and paste on the third plane, edit the expression "location*3".

Paste the driver on 4th plane and edit "location*4".

And so on ...

Comment: Boom!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks Josh!

Comment: Hey Josh, mind if I ask another question?  What would the Driver formula be to make all the objects rotate, as the Control Object rotates, but where each one rotates more than the one before it?  I'm playing around with the Edit Driver menu but I keep getting a "python error" message with all of my inputs.

Comment: As rules of this site, you should ask a new question with new title.

Comment: OK:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270410/driven-rotational-formula