# Driven Rotational Formula

Tags: drivers

I want to rotate a stack of planes using a control empty as the driver, but I want each plane to move a little bit more than the one below it.

What would the formula for this be in the driven properties?

Comment: why do you want a driver? you could simple use an array modifier...?

Comment: Rotate about which axis? You mean spin in their own plane?

Comment: @chris can't use an array because every object will be different

Comment: @RobinBetts Sorry, should have said: Z-axis, and yeah spin along their own origin

Comment: And is geometry nodes ok?

Comment: @Chris absolutely ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove any parent-child relationship, create an empty (control object), hover over its Z rot value and right click "Copy as new driver".

Hover over the Z rot value of the first plane and right click "Paste driver".

Hover over the Z rot value of the 2nd plane and right click "Paste driver", right click "Edit driver" switch from "Average value" to "Scripted expression" and set the expression "rotation_euler*2".

Copy this driver and paste on the third plane, edit the expression "rotation_euler*3".

Paste the driver on 4th plane and edit "rotation_euler*4".

And so on ...

[image]

Comment: Once again, thanks Josh!  Strangely, when I tried to do this per your last answer to my previous question, it didn't work with the rotation. I kept getting "python error."  No clue what I was doing wrong but it's working now so cheers.

Comment: Probably some little syntax mistakes, like capitals or spaces or dots.